# How would I find the value of an unspecified variable in other objects of the same class? C#

Tags: c#, class, object, variables, methods

I want this method to work with any variable - i.e., passing a "Price" value to the method then getting the total price of all items.

```
private int GetTotalValue(int stat){
    int total = 0;
    foreach(Item i in Vendor.items){
        totalStat += i.stat;
    }
    return total;
}
```

However, it has no way of knowing the name of the variable that I passed as the parameter, and thus no way of accessing it in other objects.

How would I tell the method what variable I'm passing, instead of just the value of it?

Comment: Typically this is done by passing a lambda. In fact, LINQ already has a method for doing this. `total = Vendor.items.Sum(i => i.Price);`

Comment: If you know which property you want to sum at compile time, th given answer works but if you decide it at runtime then you will need reflection or expression trees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want the sum of some property value you could encapsulate that logic into a method, e.g. GetVendorItemSum:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] {
            new Item {Price = 1},
            new Item {Price = 2}
                            };
        var vendor = new Vendor {Items = items};

        var vendorSum = GetVendorItemsSum(vendor, x => x.Price);
    }

    private static int GetVendorItemsSum(Vendor vendor, Func<Item, int> func)
    {
        return vendor.Items.Sum(func);
    }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items;
}

public class Item
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```